# How to make in input the first letter capitalized?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make in input the first letter capitalized? Css method text-transform: capitalize; does not fit.

```js
var positions = $('ul li');

var inputSearch = $('input');
inputSearch.val('').on('input', function(e){
  var terms = this.value.toLowerCase().split(/[\s,.]+/);

  positions.each(function(){
    var text = this.innerText.toLowerCase();

    this.hidden = !terms.every(function(term){
      return text.indexOf(term) !== -1;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="placeholder">

<ul>
  <li>wrew</li>
  <li>w</li>
  <li>rew</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "*text-transform: capitalize; does not fit*" -- Why? What's wrong with that as a solution?

Comment: I want only the first letter to be capitalized

Comment: `li::first-letter {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}`

Comment: Why was my XY problem statement deleted?  This question has not clearly stated what the problem is.  Only what they want.

Comment: @j08691 in input

Comment: What does "in input" mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li').each(function(index, elem){
  var text = $(elem).text();
  text = text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1);
  $(elem).text(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below. This code will track when you press the key, and when you do, it'll get the current value of the input (before the key you pressed is added). It would then check if the last character in the input field is a space. If it is, it'll add to `text` the key you just pressed, but uppercase. If not, it'll simply add the key you just pressed to `text`

Then, the next time you press **any** key, the value of the input would change the the value of `text`, which would have the first letter of every word capitalized.

```js
var text = "";
var val;

$(".input").keypress(function(e) {
  val = $(this).val();
  if (val[val.length - 1] == ' ') {
    text += e.key.toUpperCase();
  }
  else {
    text += e.key;
  }
});

$(".input").keydown(function() {
  $(this).val(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="Placeholder" class="input" />
```